# Authenticate user by WindowsIdentity in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: authentication

I have external authentication system that returns WindowsIdentity by user name and one time password. I am trying to use it with FBA and Claims-Based Authentication. I have created my custom login page. On Authenticate event of login control I can get user's WindowsIdentity, but I don't know how say to SharePoint that it is authenticated user.

Thanks for any help or advice.

Comment: Did you manage to integrate the ideas specified in the above answer to create a sample?
I am new to Sharepoint and I want to achieve the same thing as the one posted by you. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This only applies to SharePoint 2010.

What you need is a SAML token that SP can consume, so I believe you have to write an Identity Provider (IP) to plug into the SharePoint STS (Security Token Service). In that IP, you will implement the Authenticate(..) interface using code like this:

```
if(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().IsAuthenticated)
{
    return AuthenticationResult.Authenticated;
}
else
{
    return AuthenticationResult.NotAuthenticated; // Caller will then 302 to Login page
}
```

Here's an overview of the process:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/russmax/archive/2010/05/27/understanding-sharepoint-2010-claims-authentication.aspx

The programming details are hard to come by, but there are a few articles online and the book "Programming Windows Identity Foundation" is excellent. I've been meaning to do an article on this subject, but have not yet, otherwise I would just send you the code.

rlr